# lidR: Error in .bboxCoords(coords) : nrow(coords) > 0 is not TRUE

Tags: r, lidar, lidr

I'm using `lidR` to create some lidar metric rasters that match the layout of Landsat images. In the `lidR` documentation it says this can be done simply by using a `RasterLayer` instead of a resolution in the grid functions.

```
las <- readLAS(here("data/lumber1.las"))
evi <- raster(here("data/ls8_evi.tif"))
projection(las) <- projection(evi)
point_density <- grid_density(las, evi)
```

The code is simple but I get

```
Error in .bboxCoords(coords) : nrow(coords) > 0 is not TRUE
```

when I run the `grid_density()` function and I'm not sure how to get around this. If I use a number as the resolution instead of a raster all the grid functions work.

```
> print(evi)
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 10000, 10000, 1e+08  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent     : 1484415, 1784415, 1364805, 1664805  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : C:/Users/.../R/lidR_test/data/ls8_evi.tif 
names      : ls8_evi 
values     : -2.496704, 2.983905  (min, max)

> print(las)
class        : LAS (LASF v1.4)
point format : 6
memory       : 994.8 Mb 
extent       :2e+06, 2005000, 230000, 235000 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref.  : NA 
area         : 25 kunits²
points       : 11.34 million points
density      : 0.45 points/units²
names        : X Y Z gpstime Intensity ReturnNumber NumberOfReturns ScanDirectionFlag EdgeOfFlightline Classification ScannerChannel Synthetic_flag Keypoint_flag Withheld_flag Overlap_flag ScanAngle UserData PointSourceID
```

Comment: Please edit your post to add more information about both `las` and `evi`. At least a `print`.

Comment: Sure, I just added that in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your raster and your point cloud don't share overlapping bounding boxes. They are likely to be in different projections. Using `projection(las) <- projection(evi)` does not re-project the point cloud (neither `projection(evi) <- projection(las)` re-project the raster). `projection()` only set a CRS.

Your `LAS` does not have any coordinate reference system. You must first find the CRS of the point cloud then re-project the raster.

```r
crs <- "a valid proj4string"
projection(las) <- crs
evi2 <- projectRaster(evi, crs=crs)
```

But raster re-projection is not a lossless transformation. Maybe you should simply use `res = 30`.

Btw you found a limit case that is weakly handled by `lidR`. I will put a more informative message in next release.